# Finding the column names of a pandas DataFrame where row values are minimum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame as below:

```
X = np.array([[1.0, -20, 200, 50],
              [2.0, 19, 100, 52],
              [3.0, 17, -150, 55],
              [4.0, 20, -120, 60],
              [5.0, 21, 119, 70],
              [6.0, -15, 134, -75],
              [7.0, 9, 178, -80],
              [8.0, 10, -190, 90],
              [9.0, 19, 200, 70],
              [10.0, 20, 210, 65]])

native_id1 = ['08MB005', '08ME005', '08GD006','08GH002']
native_id2 = ['08CD001', '08EF006', '08TH002', '08LO002', '07HP003', '08IK002', '09WF001','09YU001', '05KJ008', '08LK007']
X = pd.DataFrame(X, native_id2, native_id1)
```

I have used the function below which returns the position of the column or index corresponding to minimum values in each row.

```
idx = np.argmin(X.values, axis=1)
```

which returns something like:

```
array([1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

What I was looking for was this:

```
08CD001    08ME005
08EF006    08MB005
08TH002    08GD006
08LO002    08GD006
07HP003    08MB005
08IK002    08GH002
09WF001    08GH002
09YU001    08GD006
05KJ008    08MB005
08LK007    08MB005
```

*** UPDATED ***
I have found the answer to this question where I was trying to find the column name corresponding to minimum value of each row of a pandas dataframe.

The answer below worked:

```
df.idxmin(axis=1)
```

Comment: `df.columns[idx]`

Comment: This will not work as it looks within just the array of column names - will not find the minimum values of each row.

Comment: If you really want to be clear, you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: @SinaShabani you asked for the column names in your question...that is what `df.columns[idx]` gives you. It gives you the column name where the min value is for every row

Comment: @SinaShabani There is a deep connection between `pandas` and `numpy`. `type(df.columns.values)` or `type(df.values)` returns `numpy.ndarray`, so you shouldn't think of them as incompatible libraries.

Comment: It show you did not read my question carefully - I did not ask for column names I asked for column names where the value of each row is minimum - I am going to update the question now with a mimimal,complete, and verifiable example. @Chris

Comment: @SinaShabani that's what it does

Comment: `df.idxmin(axis=1)` will get you all the column names

Comment: You still haven't provided what you expect the output to be.

Comment: @Mstaino Thanks - this is what I was looking for

Comment: @piRSquared I mentioned column names

Comment: BTW `(X.idxmin(1) == X.columns[X.values.argmin(1)]).all()` evaluates to `True`

Comment: It is clear that you never even tried the code I offered.  If you had, you'd have noticed that it gives the column names for the minimal value in each row... Exactly what you asked for.  Now I didn't lose or gain anything from this interaction but I fear you'll walk away not understanding something that may be very useful to you.

Comment: @piRSquared that code works - but I got it solved with the way MSTAINO mentioned earlier  - I am giving upvotes to all your comments but for some reason people just give downvotes to questions of people like me who have an actual problem - this is so sad - and I have no idea why you are so aggressive with comments - I have clearly got my problem solved with a simpler approach and was thankful to your comments as gave 3 upvotes - where is this anger coming from?

Comment: No, the downvotes are for having a confusing question in which the objective was not clear.  If it had been clear, I'd have posted an answer providing you will exactly what you asked for.  Instead, you "mentioned column names".  But in programming you need to be explicit.  Do you want column names in an array, list, dictionary, pandas.Series, set.  does order matter?  So many questions arise from being vague.  This is the point of a [mcve].  To remove ambiguity.

Comment: @SinaShabani glad it worked. I added it as an answer with the docs so you can close the question, note that you can `apply` `np.argmin` but it is not the recommended way.

Comment: Even further, if you take the time to update your question where you provide those details, I'd be more than happy to remove my downvote and possibly even upvote.

Comment: @piRSquared hoenstly, I think my question was really clear - I clearly mentioned column names of a pandas dataframe!

Comment: I'm not suggesting that I know everything, but I am familiar with answering pandas related questions.  I'd be willing to bet that if I found your desired results unclear, then others might have as well.  Of course, someone may have intuited exactly what you meant and may have provided you with exactly what you needed.  But in my opinion that does not help the community out because it is difficult to generalize when others are less likely to understand what you meant.  As I've said, you should edit your question and provide exactly what you expect to see given your example input.

Comment: @piRSquared I have done the edit on my question, can you please check if it is more clear now? and sorry if I was not clear enough. I would be glad if you can upvote my question as well.

Comment: @Mstaino I have tried to edit the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.idxmin` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html)):

```
df.idxmin(axis=1)
```

Equivalently you can use `np.argmin` in `df.apply(np.argmin, axis=1)`. But you get this warning:

> > FutureWarning: 'argmin' is deprecated. Use 'idxmin' instead. The behavior of 'argmin' will be corrected to return the positional minimum in the future. Use 'series.values.argmin' to get the position of the minimum now.

So `idxmin` is recommended

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the required columns:

```
def func(x):
    return np.argmin(x)

print(df[["Small", "Int", "Bor", "Drama"]].apply(func, axis=1))
```