# finding the indexes of the global min pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have numerical data for some function z = f(x, y) saved in a pandas dataframe, where x is the index values, y is the column values, and the dataframe is populated with the z data. For example:

```
       0.0       0.1       0.2       0.3       0.4       0.5       0.6   
1.0    0.0 -0.002961 -0.005921 -0.008883 -0.011845 -0.014808 -0.017772  
1.1    0.0 -0.002592 -0.005184 -0.007777 -0.010371 -0.012966 -0.015563 
1.2    0.0 -0.002084 -0.004168 -0.006253 -0.008340 -0.010428 -0.012517
```

is there a simple pandas command, or maybe a one-line string of a few simple commands, which returns the `(x, y)` values corresponding to data attributes, specifically in my case as `min(z)`? In the example data I'd be looking for `(1.0, 0.6)`

I'm really just hoping there's an answer that doesn't involve parsing out the data into some other structure, because sure, just linearize the data in a numpy array and correlate the numpy array index with (x,y). But if there's something cleaner/more elegant that I simply am not finding, I'd love to learn about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the column names of a pandas DataFrame where row values are minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931167/finding-the-column-names-of-a-pandas-dataframe-where-row-values-are-minimum)

Comment: No that's about as far as I've gotten so far, idxmin gives you the min values in accordance to all indexes or all columns individually, but not correlated globally.

Comment: dude, the comment you deleted was *technically* incorrect but it helped me find the answer - just had the numerical call and the index call backwards. `(df.min(1).idxmin(), df.min(). idxmin())` is what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using [pandas.DataFrame.idxmin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) & [pandas.Series.idxmin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

# df view
     0.0       0.1       0.2       0.3       0.4       0.5       0.6
1.0  0.0 -0.002961 -0.005921 -0.008883 -0.011845 -0.014808 -0.017772
1.1  0.0 -0.002592 -0.005184 -0.007777 -0.010371 -0.012966 -0.015563
1.2  0.0 -0.002084 -0.004168 -0.006253 -0.008340 -0.010428 -0.012517

# min column
min_col_name = df.min().idxmin()

# min column index if needed
min_col_idx = df.columns.get_loc(min_col_name)

# min row index
min_row_idx = df[min_col_name].idxmin()
```

another option:

```
(df.min(axis=1).idxmin(), df.min().idxmin())
```